# Completely disabling Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sass-rails

I am trying to completely remove Sprockets from a Rails 6.1.3.2 with Ruby 3.0 project

One of the Stackoverflow question/answers said that I need to remove the sass-rails gem from the Gemfile.

Per the sass-rails gem Github repo:

```
This gem provides official integration for Ruby on Rails projects with the Sass stylesheet language.
```

So, why would it have to be removed if I wanted to write .scss stylesheets instead of .css stylesheets?

Comment: The `sass-rails` gem supports Sass within the Sprockets asset pipeline. So, it's unnecessary if you remove Sprockets. Assuming you are moving solely to webpack, you'd want to include `node-sass` in your packages and configure the `sass-loader` to process `.scss` files.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. I want to use webpack only.

Comment: @rmlockerd node-sass is deprechiated. https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated

Comment: Got that, thanks. I only needed to remove the sass-rails gem and do yarn add sass-loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sass-rails` gem was actually deprecated.

It's a rails (sprockets) wrapper for the venerable Ruby SASS compiler which is extremely slow. It was [replaced in 2019](https://sass-lang.com/blog/ruby-sass-is-unsupported) by `sassc-rails` which used libsass (which is written in C) until that was also axed. In Rails 7, sassc-rails became the default. It is recommended to move away from `sass-rails`

The primary implementation of SASS is now [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass). You can install it through Node.js, Homebrew, Chocolate, Scout-App etc. You integrate it with webpack through the [Sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) package.

It supports features like the new module system `@use` that replaces the problematic `@include` that are starting to show up in cutting edge frameworks and will be blazingly fast compared to the old Ruby compiler.

Comment: Integrating it via the SASS-loader worked, following @rmlockerd advice. yarn add sass-loader, and I removed the sass-rails gem.